# values changing while saving or reading float and double values to yaml file using opencv

Tags: opencv, floating-point, yaml, double

Setup: opencv 3.2 on ubuntu 18.04.

I save an int, a float and a double value using YAML file. The values of the float and the double in the YAML file is different from the values which are written by the program.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

int main(int ac, char** av)
{
    cv::FileStorage fs("file.yaml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE); // create FileStorage object

    int a = 1;
    float b = 0.2;
    double c = 0.3;

    fs << "a" << a;
    fs << "b" << b;
    fs << "c" << c;

    fs.release(); // releasing the file.
    return 0;
}
```

The file.yaml reads

```
%YAML:1.0
---
a: 1
b: 2.0000000298023224e-01
c: 2.9999999999999999e-01
```

Also when I read the above YAML file using code belong I get altered values for the float and  the double values.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int ac, char** av)
{
    cv::FileStorage fs("file.yaml", cv::FileStorage::READ); // create FileStorage object

    int a; float b; double c;

    fs["a"] >> a;
    fs["b"] >> b;
    fs["c"] >> c;

    std::cout << "a, b, c="<< a << ","<< b << ","<< c << std::endl;

    fs.release(); // releasing the file.

    return 0;
}
```

Output of the above program and the saved YAML file:

```
a, b, c=1,0.2,0.3
```

**My question is how to read and write float and double values from/to YAML files using opencv without value alteration**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The values of the float and the double in the YAML file is different from the values which are written by the program.

`float` and `double` are represented using a floating-point format with a binary base. The values 0.2 and 0.3 are not representable in these formats. The nearest representable values are 0.20000000298023223876953125 and 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875.

The numerals written to the file, “2.0000000298023224e-01” and “2.9999999999999999e-01” differ from the represented values (shown above) but contain sufficiently many digits to uniquely identify the represented values. When read back, the resulting `float` and `double` values should equal the values shown above.

> Also when I read the above YAML file using code belong [below?] I get altered values for the float and the double values.

What do you mean by “altered values”? According to the question, the output of the “code below” is “a, b, c=1,0.2,0.3”. While 0.2 and 0.3 differ from the represented values shown above, they are what we expect to be output by default when those values are sent to `std::cout`. Most likely, what has happened is that, when “2.0000000298023224e-01” was read from the file, 0.20000000298023223876953125 was stored in the `float b`, and writing this to `std::cout` produced “0.2”, as expected, and similarly for `double c` and 0.3. What do you believe differs from this?

Comment: What about integer values. Will they be represented as the same integer. For example is it possible that integer 3 be represented as 2.99999999999 .... If that happens then value truncation may happen when I read it back into an integer variable